# Search operation at Site level in SharePoint Online using GraphServiceClient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am able to search in Document library in SharePoint Online using [GraphServiceClient](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/docs/overview.md) using below code :

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {
            await Task.Run(() => { }); 
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = 
              new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
        }));

var ddd = await client.Sites["SiteUrl"].Drives["DriveId"].Search("srchTxt").Request().GetAsync();
```

However, I did not find search method for a site like

`var ddd = await client.Sites["SiteUrl"].Search("srchTxt").Request().GetAsync();`

Is it possible to do search in a site in SharePoint Online using GraphServiceClient?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, no. SharePoint only provides search for document libraries (via [drives](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/item_search)) at the moment.

I would highly recommend posting this suggestion to [Office's User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). I can attest to the importance this User Voice site plays Office's engineering roadmap and feature planning.